# How to display saved image in a folder in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am saving image files in a folder /images/profile and i want to save the image path in a database and do not know how to display image in a view. I am new to MVC. Following are the codes for image uploading. Please help.

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        ImageEntities db = new ImageEntities();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file, tbl_Image model)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                string pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                                       Server.MapPath("~/images/profile"), pic);
                // file is uploaded
                file.SaveAs(path);

            }

    return View("FileUploaded", db.tbl_Image.ToList());

        }

        public ActionResult FileUploaded()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

FileUpload.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
                            new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{  
    <label for="file">Upload Image:</label> 
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width: 100%;" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit" /> 
}
```

FileUploadedView.cshtml

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    { 
   <img src="~/images/profile/@item.imagepath" />
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud save **image name** instead of **image path** in table.

Then in view try this:

```
<img src="~/images/profile/@Model.imageUrl" />
```

***"Update"***

See here:

[How to save image in database and display it into Views in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825119/how-to-save-image-in-database-and-display-it-into-views-in-mvc)

Comment: Now only image border is displaying not the image i have updated my code. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

save the image path like this: "~/images/profile/mypic.jpg"

and then in you view:

```
 <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/profile/mypic.jpg")" />
```

or in case you have a Photo class: (consider "item" as your image)

```
 <img src="@Url.Content(item.Path)" />
```

thats it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the suggestion of Samiey Mehdi I did this at my code for making it work

In the Controller:

`newRecord.flName = ImageName;`

In the View:

`<img src="~/images/@item.flName" width="100" height="100" />`