# How to Upload and Retrieve Images from Entity Framework using mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to asp.net mvc. I want help regarding How to Upload and Retrieve Images from Entity Framework using mvc4. Please give me step wise information.

here is my model

```
BUser
public byte[] Image { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            HMSEntities2 db = new HMSEntities2();
            string ImageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            byte[] y = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ImageName);
            string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/images/" + ImageName);

            // save image in folder
            file.SaveAs(physicalPath);

            //save new record in database
            User newRecord = new User();

            newRecord.Image = y;

            db.Users.Add(newRecord);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        //Display records
        return RedirectToAction("Display","BPatient");
    }

    public ActionResult Display()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Edit View

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload","BPatient", FormMethod.Post, new{@class = "form-horizontal role='form' container-fluid enctype='multipart/form-data' " }))
<div class="form-group">
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width: 100%;" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit" />
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20825120/4523071 i m following this tutorial..whenever i tried to upload pic it given me error...i.e (HttpPostedFileBase file ) is null

Comment: You are surrounding the form with `@using( ... ){ the html here }` ?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, let's not store the Image in the database, but rather a reference to our image.

public class BUser {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string ImagePath {get;set;}
}

Now, in our Action lets POST up the image, save it in the relevant directory, say /Images/UserImages and then store a reference to that image on our class!

So to start here is the ActionResult with references to an ImageService we are going to use:

```
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
        if (file.ContentLength > 0 &&     _imageService.IsValidImageType(file.ContentType))
        {
            const string imagePath = "/Images/UserImages/";
            string uploadedImage = _imageService.UploadImage(file, Server.MapPath(imagePath));
            string uploadedPath = string.Format("{0}{1}",imagePath, uploadedImage);

            if (uploadedPath.Contains("Fail"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Failed", "BPatient");
            }

            var bUser = new BUser() {Image = uploadedPath};
            //Save to DB
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Display", "BPatient");
}
```

In reality we don't want to bloat the Controller action this much, however I am trying to keep it similar to what you already had, so it's not a complete rewrite. Now here is the code for our service which will Upload our image, and check its a valid type of image

```
//Extract this to a service or helper
        private readonly string[] _validFileTypes = new[] { "image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg", "image/png", "image/gif" };


        public string UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase file, string path)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                    {
                        return "Fail";
                    }

                    if (!IsValidImageType(file.ContentType))
                    {
                        return "Fail";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return "Fail";
                }

                string extensionlessName = NameWithoutExtesion(file.FileName);
                string randomName = System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName();
                string pathMain = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", path, extensionlessName, randomName, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Path.GetExtension(file.FileName)));
                try
                {
                    file.SaveAs(pathMain);
                    return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", extensionlessName, randomName, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Path.GetExtension(file.FileName)));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return "Fail";
                }
            }
            return "Fail";
        }
```

And here are two small methods from the Service that will just chop down the overall size of UploadImage

```
        public bool IsValidImageType(string fileType)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileType))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (!_validFileTypes.Contains(fileType))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public string NameWithoutExtesion(string name)
        {
            if (!name.Contains("."))
            {
                return name;
            }
            int index = name.LastIndexOf('.');
            string newName = name.Substring(0, index);
            return newName;
        }
```

This is from what I can tell a working solution. Naturally it will require some more work for inserting into the database however I have left a comment there for you to put that code in.

Although the Service would work straight from a Copy-Paste the Action will need a little of your work. And once it's all hooked up I recommend you try and see what was done differently.

Comment: sorry for late reply @Glitch100...but i get a error here `if (file.ContentLength > 0 && _imageService.IsValidImageType(file.ContentType))`   and  `string uploadedImage = _imageService.UploadImage(file, Server.MapPath(imagePath));` erro is   **The name '_imageService' does not exist in the current context**

Comment: That's because I said add all those methods into a class called ImageService and then declare an instance of it for use